# Find the root of a tree in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I wrote a code that builds a binary tree, and it is built as follows:

```
[[[[discrete,68]],[linear,78],[[[[calculas1,78]],[physics1,80],[]],[physics2,90],[]]]]
```

But the problem that I face, is when I want to search in tree, I cannot find the header of the tree!

Answer (score 1):

Indenting your data, and changing some brackets to distinguish the data entries from the rest, it's

```
[ [ [ (discrete,68) ],
    (linear,78),
    [ [ [ (calculas1,78) ],
        (physics1,80),
        [] ],
      (physics2,90),
      []]]]
```

It looks like it satisfies

```
tree_list( [X] ):- tree(X).

tree( [] ).         % an empty tree
tree( [ (Key, Value) ] ).     % a leaf
tree( [ L, (Key, Value), R] ):-      % a branch
    tree(L), tree(R).
```

So your data list is not a tree, it is a list of one tree, which is

```
                (linear,78)
               /            \
    (discrete,68)           (physics2,90)
                           /             \
                     (physics1,80)       EMPTY
                    /             \
               (calculas1,78)     EMPTY
```

What's meant by a tree's root is probably

```
root( Tree, Root):- Tree=[Root], tree(Tree).       % a leaf
root( Tree, Root):- Tree=[Left, Root, Right], tree(Tree).   % a branch
```

and so for your data you can get it with

```
get_root(Data,Root):- Data=[Tree], root(Tree, Root).
```